# DerivedClass as value for ParentClass type variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, type-conversion

I am new to C# and I'm developing an rpg game engine.

I have my base class `Item` which is parent for `Weapon` and `Armour`,
weapon and armour classes have extra variables for stats, weapon slots, armour type, etc.

My `Player` class:

```
class Player{
    Armour helmet;
    Armour chest;
    Weapon mainHand;
    Item offHand;
```

and this are my methods to equip an item into his corresponding slot (setter methods)

```
    void equipItem(Item pz)
    {
        switch (pz)
        {
            case Weapon w when (w.weaponType == WeaponType.OneHandWeapon):
                mainHand = pz; // Cannot convert-to-Type Error *
                break;
            case Weapon w2 when (w2.weaponType == WeaponType.TwoHandWeapon):
                mainHand = pz; // **
                toInventory(offHand);
                offHand = null;
            case Armour a when (a.armourType == ArmourType.Chest):
                chest = pz; // **
                break;
            case Armour a when (a.armourType == ArmourType.Helmet):
                helmet = pz; // **
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    void equipOffhand(Item pz)
    {
        if (mainHand.weaponType != WeaponType.TwoHandWeapon)
        {
            offHand = pz;
        }
        else
        {
            //error cannot equip off hand while wielding 2handWeapon
        }
    }
```

Pretty Simple model.

what I want to achieve is

```
var ss = new Weapon()
{
    weaponType= WeaponType.oneHandedWeapon,
};
equipItem(ss);
equipOffHand(ss);
```

But how to get rid of the type conversion Errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using the new pattern-matching switch statement. This case, for example, will only be run if the item is of type `Weapon` and is a one hand weapon:

```
case Weapon w when (w.weaponType == WeaponType.OneHandWeapon):
```

When this case runs, `pz` will be "casted" to a `Weapon` and stored in `w`. So you can just use `w` to refer to the item, as a weapon:

```
switch (pz)
{
    case Weapon w when (w.weaponType == WeaponType.OneHandWeapon):
        mainHand = w
        break;
    case Weapon w2 when (w2.weaponType == WeaponType.TwoHandWeapon):
        mainHand = w2
        toInventory(offHand);
        offHand = null;
    case Armour a when (a.armourType == ArmourType.Chest):
        chest = a;
        break;
    case Armour a when (a.armourType == ArmourType.Helmet):
        helmet = a;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I understand what you say:
`pz` which is of type `Item` will automatically be casted to `Weapon` when the first case run,

well thats what is not intended to do, because pz will not be of  `Item` class, it will be either `Weapon` or  `Armour` which are childs of `Item`,

i don't fully know how to describe this, but i want to pz be a child class  of `item`,

but visual studio says that im missing a cast  `Item` to `Weapon` or `Armour`

Comment: @RomanSky can you try explaining your goal in another way? I don’t understand what you are trying to do. `pz`’s variable type is Item. It can store Item objects, Weapon objects or Armour objects. Your switch statement checks which type `pz` actually stores.

Comment: Im sorry, english not my native language, reading again your answer i saw you gave 

    `chest = a;`
    `helmet = a;`
not:
    `chest = pz;`
    `helmet = pz;`

and this worked, thanks

Answer (score 3):

With a proper object-oriented design, you shouldn't need enumerations to tell you where an item belongs or a switch case statement to trigger the right one-- that is a [code smell](http://wiki.c2.com/?SwitchStatementsSmell).

Picking a slot is behavior. Behavior you inherit and override and polymorphism takes care of the rest by remembering the type of the object. This approach not only gives you more structured code but will also perform a bit better (less CPU, better branch prediction, etc).

Here is a simple example which should cover most of your requirements:

```
abstract class Item
{
    public abstract void Equip(Player player);
}

abstract class Armour : Item
{
}

class ChestPlate : Armour
{
    public override void Equip(Player player)
    {
        player.Chest = this;
    }
}

class Helm : Armour
{
    public override void Equip(Player player)
    {
        player.Helmet = this;
    }
}

class Weapon : Item
{
    public override void Equip(Player player)
    {
        player.MainHand = this;
    }
}

class OneHandedWeapon : Weapon
{
}

class TwoHandedWeapon : Weapon
{
    public override void Equip(Player player)
    {
        player.Offhand = player.MainHand = this;
    }
}

class Player
{
    public Armour Helmet { get; set; }
    public Armour Chest { get; set; }
    public Weapon MainHand { get; set; }
    public Item Offhand { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you want to equip an item, you just need to do this:

```
item.Equip(player);
```

Here's a [link to a working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNQnr0) that demonstrates a bit more of how this works.

Comment: Thanks for Replying, altough i set Sweeper's answer as best because he solved my problem i will definetly try this, as you say, this approach improves code structure and readability

Thank you